# Problema ao recuperar valores do firebase para lista

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database

Eu estou fazendo uma lista, e nessa lista eu puxo as seguinte informações id, idPostagem, descrição, nomeUsuario e fotoUsuario.

Porem para popular(adicionar) dados a essa lista estou usando o seguinte trecho de código dentro de uma activity:

```
        itensSalvosRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("itens-salvos").child(idUsuarioLogado);        

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            listarItensSalvos();
        }    

        private void listarItensSalvos() {

            valueEventListener = itensSalvosRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    listaItemSalvo.clear();

                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        listaItemSalvo.add(ds.getValue(ItemSalvo.class));

                    }

                    Collections.reverse(listaItemSalvo);
                    itensSalvosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
```

Estrutura do firebase:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia é ele recuperar todos os valores, porem ele só recupera o nomeUsuario, como mostrado na foto abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que estou fazendo de errado ao popular(adicionar os valores) a essa lista?

Comment: Os nomes das propriedades da sua classe `listaItemSalvo` estão totalmente diferentes do seu banco firebase, apenas o campo `nomeUsuario` está correto, por isso apenas ele está vindo preenchido...

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro Nossa... kkk era isso mesmo, fiquei tão focado em outra coisa que acabei não pensando no  obvio, obrigado. Se quiser responder para eu marcar como resposta, pode responder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os nomes das propriedades da sua classe listaItemSalvo estão totalmente diferentes do seu banco firebase, apenas o campo nomeUsuario está correto, por isso apenas ele está vindo preenchido...

Sua classe listaItemSalvo está assim:

```
descricao
fotoPostagem
id
nomeUsuario
```

Mas o certo, acredito eu, é que deveria ser

```
feedDescricao
feedFoto
feedId
nomeUsuario
```

Tente sempre criar as suas classes dando nomes para as propriedades iguais os campos do banco, ou seja, procure sempre espelhar o banco em sua classe, isso facilita o entendimento e também deixa tudo mais pratico.

Comment: Obrigado! realmente nem prestei a atenção!